Sounddevice echoes the audio of RawOutputStream on Windows 10
i employed example script form NDI-Python library to build a test application of my own to receive and Play NDI stream. The video is played in window of OpenCV and the audio is directed to the Speakers with help of Sounddevice library. my basic interpreter is Python 3.10 and platform is Windows 10, Dell Inspiron 15 7000. i am facing a problem that audio plays good during the initial 1 to 2 seconds and then all of it keeps repeating in the background with the new audio that is playing in the foreground. i suspect that i am unable to give my app enough time to play the last buffer till it is empty or the buffer is not exactly 'zeroed' before it is filled again. this problem did occur when i played it in UBUNTU 22.04 and the problem was resolved by adjusting the default_delay value of PulseAudio from 2 msec to 200 msec. i am unable to locate such a parameter in sounddevice/PortAudio on Windows 10. your help is requested with thanks.
class exNDIPlayer():
    winIndex = 0
    siblingWindows = []
    n =0; m = 0

    def __init__(self,nameStr, source):
        super().__init__()

        if not ndi.initialize():
            print("ndi.initialize():")

        ndi_find = ndi.find_create_v2()

        if ndi_find is None:
            print("if ndi_find is None:")

        ndi_recv_create = ndi.RecvCreateV3()
        ndi_recv_create.color_format = ndi.RECV_COLOR_FORMAT_BGRX_BGRA

        ndi_recv = ndi.recv_create_v3(ndi_recv_create)

        if ndi_recv is None:
            return 0

        ndi.recv_connect(ndi_recv, source)

        ndi.find_destroy(ndi_find)
        q = queue.Queue(maxsize=40)  #maxsize=40
         # event = threading.Event()

        def audio_callback(outdata, frames, time, status):
            try:
                data = q.get_nowait() # original line of code
                n, m = data.shape
                if m == 1024:
                   if not status.output_underflow:
                        outdata [:] = data
            except queue.Empty as e:
                return
            # sd.wait(10)
            # sd.sleep(5)

        stream = sd.RawOutputStream(
            samplerate=48000, blocksize=1024, channels=2, dtype='int16', callback=audio_callback)
        # sd.default.device = 14 #'digital output'

        cv.startWindowThread()
        cv.namedWindow(nameStr, cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)

        with stream:

            while True:
                t, v, a, m = ndi.recv_capture_v2(ndi_recv, 1000)

                if t == ndi.FRAME_TYPE_VIDEO:
                    # print('Video data received (%dx%d).' % (v.xres, v.yres))
                    frame = np.copy(v.data)
                    cv.imshow(nameStr, frame)
                    # cv.resizeWindow(nameStr, 500,350) # uncomment this line if a preset view-window is always required
                    ndi.recv_free_video_v2(ndi_recv, v)
                    # continue
                if t == ndi.FRAME_TYPE_AUDIO:
                    # print('Audio data received (%d samples).' % a.no_samples)
                    data = np.zeros((a.no_channels, a.no_samples), np.int16)
                    interleaved = ndi.AudioFrameInterleaved16s()# original line of code
                    interleaved.data = data# original line of code
                    ndi.util_audio_to_interleaved_16s_v2(a, interleaved) # original line of code
                    timeout = interleaved.no_samples * 20 / interleaved.sample_rate # original line of code
                    q.put(data, timeout=timeout)  # original line of code
                    ndi.recv_free_audio_v2(ndi_recv, a)
                    # sd.wait(10)
                    # sd.sleep(5)

                if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
                    # print("q key is pressed")
                    break
        # event.wait()
        ndi.recv_destroy(ndi_recv)
        ndi.destroy()
        cv.destroyWindow(nameStr)
        # cv.destroyAllWindows()
 

i have carried out the following measures.
tried different HostAPIs like MME and DirectSound as device ID numbers but problem persisted.
tried sd.sleep(x) and sd.wait(x) where x is random int values as msec.
tried different sizes of Queue buffer and values of timeout to no avail.
wait sate of threading.event stalled the entire app for stipulated time.
